# Prove that $|C|=243$ given $C=\{(A,B):A,B\subseteq S,\; A\cup B=S\}$ and $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

**Problem:**

Let $\displaystyle S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\displaystyle C=\{(A,B):A,B\subseteq S,\; A\cup B=S\}$. Show that $\displaystyle |C|=243$.

---

I don't really know how to solve this. I know that there are $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^5\binom{5}{i}=2^5=32\;$ posible values for $A$ and the same amount of values for $B$. I tried dividing the problem in different cases (and adding up the results  at the end). I started with the case $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and got $32$ posible combination that belonged in $C$ (and fit the criteria) now I'm thinking on considering $A\subseteq B$. The problem is that I dont know how could I eventually solve for the case $A\not\subseteq B\land B\not\subseteq A\land A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ (in other words, when they have some but not all of their elements in common) There seems to be too many sub cases for this that would take way too long for me to check one by one.

Maybe I'm not taking the right approach. Please help with some hints on a different approach, help on the case $A\not\subseteq B\land B\not\subseteq A\land A\cap B\neq \emptyset$, or a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible hint I haven't tried. There are only six possible values for the size of the intersection of $A$ and $B$. Try each separately and add. You've done the case when the intersection is empty. There i just one case when the intersection has $5$ elements.

Comment: Another idea: since $243 = 3^5$, this suggests that there are 3 possibilities for each element of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.

Comment: Namely being in $A\setminus B,\, B\setminus A$ or $A\cap B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each element $x$ of $S$ there are $3$ possibilities: $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ or $x$ is in both ... so $\mid C \mid =3^{\mid S \mid}$.

Comment: Damn, that's good, that also explains why the case $A\cap B=\emptyset $ has $2^5$ solutions.

Thanks.